# Fsharp's Set seems to silently break

Tags: f#, set

I have this simple code:

```
let httpSuccessCodes =
  Set.ofSeq [HttpStatusCode.OK; HttpStatusCode.NoContent]

let httpSuccess (httpSuccessCode:HttpStatusCode) =
  Console.WriteLine("{0}", httpSuccessCode)
  httpSuccessCodes.Contains httpSuccessCode
```

Calling this code just silently exit the app, no error:

```
let isSuccess = httpSuccess stauscode
```

Funny that it works in fsharpi. I am not sure why it breaks.

Update1:

The code that works:

```
 let task = amazonS3client.GetACLAsync(getBucketAclRequest)
 task.Wait()
 let success = isHttpSuccess task.Result.HttpStatusCode
 if task.IsCompletedSuccessfully && success then
   Console.WriteLine("getBucketAcl finished successfully for bucket {0}", bucket)
   Some task.Result.AccessControlList
 else
   Console.Error.WriteLine("Could not get bucket acl: {0}", bucket)
   None
```

Update2:

```
if ((Set.ofSeq [ HttpStatusCode.OK; HttpStatusCode.NoContent; ]).Contains task.Result.HttpStatusCode) then
  Console.WriteLine("1")

if (httpSuccessCodes.Contains task.Result.HttpStatusCode) then
  Console.WriteLine("2")

if (isHttpSuccess task.Result.HttpStatusCode) then
  Console.WriteLine("3")
```

Output: 1

Comment: Your code should work fine. Obviously `stauscode` is either OK or NoContent

Comment: It just exits silently. No error. Not sure how to debug further.

Comment: What is your code which should break? So far there is only a boolean value assignment

Comment: Added the code.

Comment: The code looks good. Make sure you are looking at `Console.Error` output. Did you redirect standard error stream?

Comment: It is kind of funny. Check the latest update.

Comment: From output it looks like `httpSuccessCodes` does not contain `task.Result.HttpStatusCode`. How do you initialize `httpSuccessCodes`? Do you run f# executable or you use fsi?

Comment: I found the problem. I think it has something to do with which module I place the code. If I put it into a separate module it does not work. If I keep it in the same module it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some weird reason it matters which module the http status checking code lives. I was moving it into its own module and now it works.